# populate hidden input form fields based on URLparameters

Tags: java, javascript, php, jquery

I have a ppc landing page that I want to change the hidden value of a form field based on the URL parameter.

The field

```
  <input id="Campaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" type="hidden" value="7g012455dv5441vdf">
```

The URL would be something like mysite.com/?campaignidvalue=***7g012455dv5441vdf***

There will be other field "values" that are also based on the URL parameter, so it has to tie the "input id" (or name) to that specific value.

Comment: yes, I would have to check it doesn't break anything already in the url parameter

Comment: Just checked everything else still works in .php  vs. html so YES to php

Comment: For clarification purposes, is this related to Java at all? If it isn't, please remove the tag so that users who subscribe to the Java tag don't get confused and provide a Java answer.

Comment: yes to java / jquery - php was suggested but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: There was an error in my code.

PHP would be the easiest!

```
<?php       
        if(!empty($_GET['campaignidvalue'])) 
        {       
           echo '<input id="Campaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" type="hidden" value="'. $_GET['campaignidvalue'].'"/>';
        }

?>
```

This block will check to see if the value is passed in a GET parameter, and then echo it out into a hidden form field.

The first part:

```
if(!empty($_GET['campaignidvalue']))
```

Is checking to see if a parameter named Campaign_ID is being passed.

So your URL of:

`mysite.com/?campaignidvalue=7g012455dv5441vdf`

Would allow the code to continue, as it is not empty.

This section is the part that actually displays it on the page.

```
echo '<input id="Campaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" type="hidden" value="'. $_GET['campaignidvalue'].'"/>';
```

If you view the source of the HTML page, you would see

Comment: this does not pull url parameter into hidden form field

Comment: I can edit it to give more detail, but it is valid code to do just that.

Comment: @JoeSwindell actually it looks like what you're echoing above would not be valid HTML since the input is not being closed correctly.

Comment: @mikehomme you are correct, I just caught that error.

Answer (score -1):

By using this function:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.search);

    if(results == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
      return decodeURIComponent(results[1]);
    }
}
```

You'll be able to get any URL parameter by name, like so:

```
var cid = getParameterByName(campaignidvalue);
```

Then, once you have the value you can use jQuery to set it, like so:

```
$(function() {
   $("#Campaign_ID").val(cid);
});
```

Comment: I use something like this for my phone number

Comment: not sure if I combine both functions ? I will ask another question about it

Comment: Ok, yes, I see that from your last question 3 days ago about GetURLParameter(). Use that function instead of mine, above, and then, once the DOM is loaded use jQuery to set the value of the input field using the .val() function I mentioned above.